# Recorrer arreglo de objetos (JSON) en libreria fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fullcalendar

Tengo un problema cuando intento imprimir un arreglo de objetos que retorno de una petición con Ajax el cual es el siguiente.

```
Array [ {…}, {…} ]
0: Object { title: "prueba", start: "2021-05-05 14:00:00.000", end: "2021-05-05 14:00:00.000" }
1: Object { title: "Hola mundo", start: "2021-05-05 13:00:00.000", end: "2021-05-05 18:00:00.000" }
length: 2
```

Estoy utilizando ese arreglo de objetos (JSON) para mostrarlo dentro de la librería llamada fullcalendar donde dentro del código intento iterar ese arreglo de objetos pero me marca error, entonces intente colocando solamente data no marca error pero no imprime nada en el calendario, pero si imprimo data en la posición 0 (data[0]) si me imprime únicamente 1 registro de 2.
Si alguien podría orientarme para imprimir los 2 registros en la librería de fullcalendar.

> Imprimo solo 1 registro ya que si itero data con un ciclo for me marca
> error

```
events    : [
              data[1]
            ],
```

Imagen donde se muestra unicamnete 1 registro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos y excelente inicio de semana.

Muchas gracias por su apoyo.

Les anexo el código

Comment: Intenta hacerlo así: `events: data`

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el error que obtienes cuando intentas iterar sobre el array?